# How to get the value from merged cells in xlsx file using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to get the value from cell with `row = 11` and `column B and C`. See screenshot for more clarification.

I tried following code using `xlrd` package but it does not print anything.

```
import xlrd 

path = "C:/myfilepath/data.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(10,1)
sheet.cell_value(10,2)
```

I am not able to output the value from particular merged cells using `xlrd` package in python.

Above code should print the cell value i.e `PCHGFT001KS`

[image]

Comment: `(10,1)` and `(10,2)` are cells `A10` and `B10` - Maybe you need `(10, 2)` and `(11, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how xlrd works, but I do know how the lovely openpyxl works. You should use openpyxl! it's a robust tool for working with xlsx files. (NOT xls).

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel)
ws = wb[wb.get_sheet_names()[0]]
print(ws['B11'].value)
```

Extra:

If you want to unmerge those blocks you can do the following.

```
for items in ws.merged_cell_ranges:
ws.unmerge_cells(str(items))
wb.save(excel)
```